# Which verb to use when sentence has both singular and plural nouns

Tags: word-choice, verb-agreement

For example:

> The floor plan and room numbers __ updated

I want to say `are` because of `room numbers`.  However `floor plan` is singular.

*The room numbers and floor plan is updated* and *The floor pland and room numbers is updated* does not sound correct.

What is the rule?
In my example there is technically one floor plan which has many room numbers, if it matters.

Comment: If you have an *"and",* even if both pieces are singular, you use a plural verb (except in certain exceptional circumstances): *"The floor plan and cost estimate **have been** updated."*

Comment: Of course, if you have an "**or**" instead of an "**and**", then you have real agreement problems. _Either Bill or his brothers [is/are] coming early._

Comment: @JohnLawler woulnd't `will be` solve that?

Comment: Of course. But the modal is purely for show, to lock out the agreement problem. This is what's generally been happening in English for the last millennium or so -- we've been avoiding inflectional problems with syntactic crutches. Mostly involving auxiliary verbs and contractions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the verb is referring to multiple objects (the floor plan *and* the room numbers), you should use its plural form (I agree with [AmandaWitt](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/36469/amanda-witt) that "have been" is better):

> The floor plan and room numbers **have** been updated.

If you were referring to the floor plan *alone* the singular would be correct:

> The floor plan **has** been updated.

If you were referring to the room numbers only, the plural form would be correct since multiple room numbers have been updated:

> The room numbers **have** been updated.

Comment: chosen for taking the time to explain

Answer (score 1):

"The room numbers and floor plan have both been updated."