# Should I use plural or singular with "or"?

Tags: verb-agreement

Which of these sentences are correct?

```
1. The songs or the title of the playlist was updated.
2. The songs or the title of the playlist were updated.
3. the title or the songs of the playlist was updated.
4. The title or the songs of the playlist were updated.
```

Comment: We have lots of questions where your *or* is *and* but I'm not sure we have a question about *or.* There are comments on [an *and* question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/102179/which-verb-to-use-when-sentence-has-both-singular-and-plural-nouns?rq=1) which are relevant, though.

Comment: I would be inclined to make both alternatives singular (or plural), for example "The content or the title of the playlist was updated".

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["My brother or one of my sisters" — singular or plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68235/my-brother-or-one-of-my-sisters-singular-or-plural) [@tchrist's monumental answer includes 'The rule in English for when you have disjunction in a compound subject (meaning two of more separate subjects connected by an “or”, or by a “either ... or”, or by an “neither ... nor”), is that the verb agrees with the nearer subject – or nearest, if there are more than two.']

Comment: Questions like this, while having a perhaps technically correct answer (which you'd have to argue for), will still result in something that doesn't sound right to somebody. If something is so awkward that it sounds wrong no matter how it's constructed, then rephrase it: *Either **the songs** of the playlist **were** updated, or **its title was**.*

Answer (score 0):

> The songs or the title of the playlist was updated.
>
> The title or the songs of the playlist were updated

As a general rule, you decide the verb on the basis of singularity or plurality of the **nearest** subject ([ref.](https://examples.yourdictionary.com/examples-of-subject-verb-agreement.html)).

- In **example 1**, if it was *titles*, then it would be more grammatical to use **were**
- In **example 2**, if it was *song*, then *was* would be more apposite.

Comment: I agree. There is an implied "Either" that fronts the sentences: *"[Either] the songs or the title **was** updated."* ++ *"[Either] the playlist or the songs **were** updated."*